# different css style for last each entrys

Tags: php, mysql, css

I have a code that changes every second style of an each.

```
<?= $k % 2 == 1 ? 'news-figure' : 'news-figure-b' ?>
```

Is it possible to set a new style for the last entrys?

Comment: You could use something like this: `li:last-child`

Comment: Besides `last-child` you can eliminate the code doing the mod 2 by using CSS `nth-of-type`, for example alternating colored list items can be done with `li:nth-of-type(2n+1) { background-color:red; } li:nth-of-type(2n) { background-color:green; }`

Comment: Yes that works for me thank you, i used nth-last-of-type

Answer (score 3):

You can use the pseudo element `:last-child` to apply a css style.

Read more here : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

Comment: [MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org/) and [Web Platform Docs](http://www.webplatform.org/) are better references than w3schools, which has a history of being outright wrong; so much so that w3fools.com was created. MDN [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)